# consecutive numbers tag template in django

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a ranking that only return a top 3, this is the queryset

```
queryset = Ranking.objects.filter(puzzle_id=self.kwargs['pk']).order_by('segundos')[:3]
```

In my template i have a table:

```
<tbody>
       {% for ranking in object_list %}
        <tr>
          <th scope="row"></th>
          <td>{{ranking.usuario}}</td>
          <td>{{ranking.segundos}}</td>          
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

In the first `<th>` tag i need a template tag that return 1 in the first row, 2 in the second row, and 3 in the third row, i know that the solution could be pretty simple but i have trying without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [forloop.counter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/templates/builtins/#for) variable available inside the `{% for %}` loop:

```
{% for ranking in object_list %}
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
    <td>{{ranking.usuario}}</td>
    <td>{{ranking.segundos}}</td>          
  </tr>
{% endfor %}
```